# Netcat on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, netcat

Is anybody else not able to get `nc -lp 8888` working on Mac OS X? Is there another way to get this to work?

Comment: How does it not work?  Does it return an error?

Comment: I am not near a mac right now, but it returns the useage. `nc -lp 8888` works on my Ubuntu box.

Comment: Had never heard of this until reading a book on Docker. They also mention something called socat, which is supposedly this command on steriods. More info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808543/install-socat-on-mac and here https://linux.die.net/man/1/socat and here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnwZA1GRqkw

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It looks to me as if the `-p` option does nothing on the OS X version of netcat. To get it to work, I must do `nc -l localhost 8888`.

Comment: Unless installed from homebrew, then `nc -l -p 8888` works.

Comment: From `man nc`:

`-l      ... It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the -p, -s, or -z options. ...`

You probably want to just stick with @kzh's command there

Comment: @fatuhoku I just checked my manual, and yest it does say that in there, but the weird thing is that if I do `nc -lp 8888` or `nc -l -p 8888` it will then take `-p` to mean listening port. So my distributed copy does not listen to its own manual!

Comment: Agreed! Flags are a bit too expressive... it should have just refused to do any useful work, output a message and quit!

Comment: Works also with nc -l 8888

Comment: No matter the man page said that it is an error to use **-p** option in conjunction with the **-l** option. Actually, only **nc -l -p 8081** work in my mbp. That's crazy. :(

Comment: Confirming that this works for me: `nc -lvn 8080` vs. the recommended `nc -lvnp 8080`. `p` and `l` do not work when used together on the Mac OS version.

Comment: Even on Ubuntu 20 I'm finding this quirk (for UDP).

Comment: This is the best answer, but I find that `nc -lk localhost 8888` is what I wanted - since the `-k` keeps it listening after the first connection.

Answer (score 27):

Here's how this is working for me on OS X 10.10, with either the installed BSD version, or the one from Homebrew:

## BSD Version

When using the BSD version that ships with OS X, a server can be started like this

```
/usr/bin/nc -l 9999
```

## Homebrew

- Install using Homebrew: `brew install netcat`
- This will install v0.7.1 of http://netcat.sourceforge.net/
- One can use either the `nc` or `netcat` command. `nc` is an alias for `netcat`.

To start a server:

```
nc -l -p 9999
```

To start a client:

```
nc targethost 9999
```

To get the manpage of this version, one needs to use `man netcat`, as `man nc` will open the manpage of the BSD version.

Answer (score 12):

I needed to test a web service over SSL, which ncat (made by the nmap team) supports.

```
brew install nmap
ncat -C --ssl api.somecompany.com 443
```

https://nmap.org/ncat/

Answer (score 10):

nc on MacOS has too many bugs, and Apple did none patch for years.
the netcat from homebrew is a very low version.
use ncat from nmap instead

Comment: +1, as of today, `netcat --version` is `0.7.1`  (2003) for `brew install`ed `netcat`. Terrible.

Comment: Get the `nmap` version [here (link)](https://nmap.org/book/inst-macosx.html)

Comment: "`nc` on MacOS has too many bugs" -> I can only confirm this.  Fiddling around with it today and facing some inconsistent behaviours. I believe [this version of nc from 2005](https://opensource.apple.com/source/netcat/netcat-49.40.1/netcat.c.auto.html) is the one that they're still using. Ended up using [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) instead: `brew install socat`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the nc manual from Mac:

> NC(1)                                             General Commands
> Manual                                             NAME
> nc – arbitrary TCP and UDP connections and listens

```
-l      Used to specify that nc should listen for an incoming connection rather than initiate a connection to a remote
             host.
```

**It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the -p, -s, or -z options.**  *Additionally, any
timeouts specified with the -w option are ignored.*

Working example:

> nc -lv 9001