# Why is netcat not running like it should on my macOS?

Tags: macos, netcat

I tried running `nc -lnvp 1234 > filename.log` on my macOS today and it returned this error saying I need to specify a port number, while I specified the port number on my command.

This command always works on my Debian and Ubuntu, is there a reason why its different on macOS?

[image]

I tried the same command in my Debian based machine and it worked.

What should I do?

Comment: I can't figure out why it's complaining (your syntax looks right according to the usage text there), but do keep in mind that just on Linux there are 5 or 6 different programs all named "nc" with similar but not identical usages – even Debian has two – so it's not that surprising that Apple wrote their own for macOS.

Comment: i did `man nc` and it says i am running netcat, however i cant seem to get the version no matter what command i use, and its not specified in the manual what option returns the version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Netcat on Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/115553/netcat-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: Broader picture: "everything is a file" in \*nix unfortunately does not apply to network sockets. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/141020/108618): "if Unix had integrated TCP/IP I/O into the filesystem from the start, we wouldn't have the `netcat` vs `socat` vs `Ncat` vs `nc` mess, the cause of which was the same design weakness that lead to the disk imaging and wiping tool proliferation on Windows: lack of an acceptable OS facility". Plan 9 fixed this design misstep and I wish all Unix-like systems work out a single universal interface some day. (Silly me?)

Answer (score 2):

From [ss64.com man nc/netcat](https://ss64.com/osx/nc.html)

```
-l  Listen for an incoming connection rather than initiate a connection
    to a remote host.  It is an error to use this option in conjunction 
    with the -p, -s, or -z options.
```

Comment: why not?, if im waiting for a connection does netcat use a random port for that connection and why is it different on linux where i have to specify a port number?

Comment: I have no idea. You'd have to ask Apple.